# "getting dressed my clothes"? What is this?

Tags: sentence-meaning

So i saw a question on a test and I'm not sure what it means. It said, and I quote, "I am getting dressed my clothes now". I think it's wrong, but my teacher says it's right. pls help

Comment: If it is meant to be a single complete sentence, your teacher is wrong. However the sequence of words could be used in conversation, as "I am getting dressed. My clothes now", which has a sentence followed by a non-sentence request to be given "my clothes".

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. It looks like maybe it's meant to be "I am getting dressed **into** my clothes now", which makes sense but sounds weird, because "into my clothes" is redundant. "I'm getting dressed now" would be the natural way to say you were putting clothes on.

Comment: Your teacher doesn't know what they are talking about!

Comment: Thanks guys(or girls). I was feeling downtrodden but I feel a whole lot better now.  ^-^

Answer (score 2):

It is wrong.

The verb phrase "get dressed" does not have a direct object.

You might say  "I am getting dressed in my clothes now" or "... into my clothes now".  But that sounds weird because "in my clothes" is redundant.  The natural sentence is just "I'm getting dressed now."

Or you can use a different verb: "I'm putting on my clothes now."

Comment: "I'm getting dressed in a suit" or something of that sort would make sense though, right?

Comment: Yes, it would make sense.,